# How can a server identify a nodejs client (no browser) apart from its IP address?

Tags: node.js, security, https, server, http-headers

Say I have a nodejs script that makes an API request. What ways are there for a server to identify me? I know how this works with individual Browser settings, cookies etc. and I also know that IP addresses are being used. But what if I am not making the request from a Browser, but via a simple nodejs script? What ways are left to the server?

Answer (score -1):

The most rudimentary "check" a site can do to detect the presence of a browser is to force a JavaScript challenge like cloudflare does when you enable the "I'm under attack" setting.

Comment: interesting, but how could a server identify me when I am using a node.js script only (no browser)?

Comment: they might not be able to distinguish between a nodejs VS php scraper, but they'll be at least able to detect that you're not using a browser. That is enough to flag you as a "bot"